# How can I make TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run consume less CPU time

Tags: java, performance, web-services, tcp, cpu

I'm developing a webservice application, using apache cxf. Basically What this webservice does is searching a psql database using hibernate and returning the results.

The problem with this service is that it's kind of slow. When I run it LOCALLY on jetty and make the client request the data, then the VisualVM Profiler points out that **sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.ConnectionHandler.run** consumes 80% of the CPU time. All other functions in the list are less than 5%.

I suspect that this function is involved in transfering the data from service to client. Both run locally however, so I wouldn't expect this transfer to take this much CPU time. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this in profiling the client or the server process, or both?

Comment: Does it consume 80% of "CPU time" or just 80% of "time"? In other words, is it doing anything during that time, or just waiting?

Comment: @Branko He's profiling using VisualVM, which I've read count wall-clock time rather than CPU time, and this observation is confirmed by next to no CPU usage..

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect that this function is involved in transfering the data from
>   service to client

No, it is involved in unmarshalling, locating, executing, and marshalling the entire RMI call from go to whoa. If it is taking 80% of CPU time that is almost certainly because your remote methods are taking 80% of CPU time.

Comment: Does this mean that 80% is normal?

Comment: @Coos Baakman that depends *entirely* on what your undisclosed remote method(s) actually does/do. `while (true);` would consume 100%, would it not?